# Why am I obtaining an imaginary part for my integration

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I try to solve an integration as follows,

$$\int \frac{sy^{-1}}{(1+sy^{-1})} \text{exp}(-\sqrt{y})dy$$

as you can see its pretty complicated, and I get an answer like the following using Wolfram Alpha
$$e^{-i \sqrt{s}} s \left(e^{2 i \sqrt{s}} \text{Ei}\left(-i \sqrt{s}-\sqrt{y}\right)+\text{Ei}\left(i \sqrt{s}-\sqrt{y}\right)\right)$$

My question is I dont understand where this imaginary part is coming from? Any thoughts?

Comment: The result is twice the real part of a complex number.

Comment: You can try adding an "Assumptions-> s $\in$ Reals" in the Integrate[] function.

Comment: @user_of_math is this the way it should be written Integrate[(s*y^-1)/(1+s*y^-1)* exp(-\sqrt(y)),{y}, Assumptions-> s \in Real]

Comment: i think $Ei$ stands for exponential integral

Comment: yup thats true but I don't understand where the imaginary is coming from

Comment: Use the "Basic MathInput" palette of Mathematica - it has the "belongs to" symbol.

Comment: Integrate[(s*y^-1)/(1+s*y^-1)* exp(-\sqrt(y)),{y}, Assumptions->s\
\[Element] Reals]? @user_of_math

Comment: No, no it is a symbol that looks like $\epsilon$ (but is above the rows of Greek letters in the Basic MathInput palette). Spell "Reals" just as you would write it in English, "Reals".

Comment: Ok got it but I spelt Reals in my comment above the same way you did, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complex form comes from the fact that, after subbing $y=u^2$, you get an integral of the form

$$\int du \frac{2 s u}{s+u^2} e^{-u} $$

This is a deceptively nasty integral.  The only way to get something even remotely recognizable is to use partial fractions, which delivers complex numbers:

$$\frac{2 s u}{s+u^2} = s \left (\frac1{u-i \sqrt{s}} - \frac1{u+i \sqrt{s}} \right ) $$

The antiderivatives are then expressed in terms of those Ei functions.